# Handle apostrophe in query string using python

Tags: python, sql, string, python-3.x, amazon-redshift

I am trying to query Redshift using Python. 
I am generating a query string which looks like the one below:
I am using `psycopg2` as the library to establish the connection.

```
Select lat, lon, gender from table_x where x_name = "namestring"
```

If my name string contains an `'`, the query string fails to execute.

Can someone tell me a way to avoid this error? I have a list of approximately 25k names and hence escaping each of them with a `\'` is not an option.

Comment: If you're iterating over your namestrings, can't you just escape the quote mark there, before executing the query?

Comment: The ANSI standard way to escape a single quote is to double it up, i.e. use `''` inside the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a parametrized query as strongly suggested in http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html

```
# somethin along the lines of this should work:

from psycopg2 import sql

names = [ "A", "McDiff", "Old'McDonal"]

for n in names:
    cur.execute(sql.SQL("Select lat, lon, gender from {} where x_name = %s")
                .format(sql.Identifier('table_x')),[n])
```

This avoids the problem of self-quoting dur to using parametrized query construction instead of string concattenation.

---

See [Little Bobby Tables / Exploit of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/) and google sql injection fo rother reasons not to string-concattenate.

Comment: Can you please help with the scenario when the table name is a join clause? How does the `sql.identifier` work in the case of a join?

Comment: @SumedhaNagpal No, I can not. Please refer to the documentation. What you are asking (about ' destroying your query) is common over any number of Sql-Like queries - using parametrized queries is the solution to that. As for joint querys, use the API provided by psycopg and research it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes in the string and use the parametrized string to substitute with your values.

```
QUERY = """select lat, lon, gender from table_x where x_name = '{namestring}'"""
for namestring in list_of_namestrings:
    cur.execute(QUERY.format(namestring=namestring)
```

This should solve your purpose, you can make the QUERY as complex as you desire, and make the required substitutions using `.format()`